# Is there any method for converting String into Number?

Tags: javascript

## Javascript

I am a beginner, and I have a problem with 1 task;

let numbers='1.54,4.005,6,2.1,3.50';

I am trying to create an array where I will push these strings as numbers, to get array like this;

array=[1.54, 4.006, 6, 2, 1, 3.50];
I tried several methods; parseInt, numbers*1, Number(numbers). but it does not work.
Please assist.

Comment: `const array = numbers.split(',').map(n => Number(n))` should do it. (Or the shorter, but less obvious form of `.map(Number)` instead of `.map(n => Number(n))` - but this won't work with everything, it just "happens" to work with `Number` because it looks only at a single argument.)

Comment: Thanks :) Nope, it is not working, , Result: [ 1, NaN, NaN, NaN, 50 ]

Comment: What do you mean? You can [see here](https://jsfiddle.net/qn65oxd2/) that it works. Please include the full code that's failing for you in your question, ideally as runnable snippet so we can see it live.

Comment: My bad, I incorrectly put "." instead of ",", thank you so much :)) It is working now <3

Answer (score 1):

You can split the string on commas to create an array, then use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to convert each element. The [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus), [`parseFloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat), or the [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number) function can convert a string to a number.

```js
let numbers='1.54,4.005,6,2.1,3.50';
let res = numbers.split(',').map(x => +x);
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string into an array of strings, then use [Number](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/Number) on each item with
[Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
numbers.split(',').map(Number);
```

Comment: @CherryDT your link points to this page